# Errors including markdown my project

Tags: pdftex, mactex, markdown

I want to add markdown to my tex file and i'm having a really hard time doing so. i've added the package but i keep running into the same error. Here's my setup:

[image: mytex file]

And the PDFlatex run command is like so:

[image]

Also including markdown files is not working either.

Comment: it would be safer to set up a custom command that uses shell-escape, I wouldn't make shell-escape the default for all pdflatex use. It is disabled by default with good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run the document with the `shell-escape` option:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape <file>
```

change the order in your configuration:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Comment: thanks for pointing it out! works now!